# Does Simpson's Paradox affect if the researcher can conclude that alcohol consumption is related to gender?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, self-study, simpsons-paradox

I am preparing for my statistics final and have this question in the review package to answer:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/QRKGigB.png]

I understand the hypothesis portion of the question. How should I approach the first question: **Can the researcher conclude that alcohol consumption is related to gender?**

Does the answer involve using Simpson's Paradox?

Comment: I am not a statistician and don't play one on TV either, but I would be highly suspicious of the results of a researcher who concluded from the above data that alcohol consumption is related to gender. Very close to $1/3$rd of each population falls into the three categories...

Comment: If you can answer the hypothesis section well, then that should help you with the substantive question.  If you have a hypothesis test in mind, think through exactly what null hypothesis it is looking for evidence against, and how does that relate to the possible link.

Comment: What are you having trouble with? Coming up with the right statistical test? Interpreting the results? Something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simpson's paradox is not really something you can use but something that can happen in some situations. In this case, it would not be possible to observe it as it requires a third variable to be in play. You can therefore try to address this particular problem without worrying about it.